# My Code is vanished after I push To the GIT

Tags: git

Here is what I did

```
git status
git add .
git commit - m "message"
git checkout branchName
git push origin branchName
```

then message comes with Everything is up to date
but My old code is gone. please help me thanks

Comment: It seems you commit your code in a branch and then checkout and push another branch. you should know which branch when you run git commit and push that branch to remote

Comment: You changes bransch after committing. Change back to whatwvwr bransch you were on before and you'll find your code.

Comment: I hate typing on phones :/ never notice the mistakes until much later.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog is your friend. It will tell you what you did exactly and where your changes are. Git has its own versioning system under the hood for you to be able to go back and revert your commands, but also just simply see what you did.